# clamav clamdscan exit code 2 any way to troubleshoot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, clamav

clamav 0.103.8-1.amzn2

when doing `clamdscan file` it simply returns exit code 2, while `clamscan file` worked fine

installed rpm

```
clamav-0.103.8-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64.rpm
clamav-filesystem-0.103.8-1.amzn2.0.2.noarch.rpm
clamav-lib-0.103.8-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64.rpm
clamav-update-0.103.8-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64.rpm
libtool-ltdl-2.4.2-22.2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64.rpm

##install
rpm -Uvh /tmp/install/clamav/*
```

is there anyway to perform any further troubleshoot?